# How to run Stanford CoreNLP for lemmatization on Google Colab?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, google-colaboratory

There is a similar question made, however google colab change a lot since that time, I was wondering how to use Stanford CoreNLP on Google Colab, specially for lemmatization.

**Expected answer:**

- import the module
- lemmatize with a sample code

**Using the code:**

```py
!pip install stanfordnlp
import stanfordnlp
stanfordnlp.download("es")
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma')
doc = nlp("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.")
print(*[f'word: {word.text+" "}\tlemma: {word.lemma}' for sent in doc.sentences for word in sent.words], sep='\n')

%tb

------------
Loading: tokenize
With settings: 
{'model_path': '/root/stanfordnlp_resources/en_ewt_models/en_ewt_tokenizer.pt', 'lang': 'en', 'shorthand': 'en_ewt', 'mode': 'predict'}
Cannot load model from /root/stanfordnlp_resources/en_ewt_models/en_ewt_tokenizer.pt
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2890: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

*any advice to improve the question will be considered*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's better to use the new `StanfordNLP` instead of their old `CoreNLP`.

```py
!pip install stanfordnlp
import stanfordnlp
stanfordnlp.download("en")
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma')
doc = nlp("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.")
print(*[f'word: {word.text+" "}\tlemma: {word.lemma}' for sent in doc.sentences for word in sent.words], sep='\n')
```

You will get this output

```
word: Barack    lemma: Barack
word: Obama     lemma: Obama
word: was   lemma: be
word: born  lemma: bear
word: in    lemma: in
word: Hawaii    lemma: Hawaii
word: .     lemma: .
```

Here's an [example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ArL5x_XTCfRr6tSG3A-SodQUoZqp1n8e).

Comment: I'll try this in a moment. However, do yo know how can I download the spanish core on google?

Comment: Maybe stanfordnlp.download("es")

Comment: I'm asking this basic question, because I thought I was doing it wrong. I'm getting an Exception. I updated it in the question

Comment: Add stanfordnlp.Pipeline(lang="es") as well.